# How to insert specific extracted array elements into a new array with right structure

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table, datatables

I have 1 variable which is *very* long (about 600 lines of code (1 line for each human)) and contains 16 different pieces of information about the 600 humans. I have to extract just 4 pieces of information and have done so by using

```
var foo = myArray.map(a => a.foo);
var bar = myArray.map(a => a.bar);
var foo2 = myArray.map(a => a.foo2);
var bar2 = myArray.map(a => a.bar2);
```

I wish to insert all these informations into a table and have written a code which is able to do so:

```
myArray.forEach(function(items) {
var row = document.createElement("tr");
    items.forEach(function(item) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.textContent = item;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
});
```

My problem is now that the code above is only able to do so if if I reference to an array (example above "myArray"). I haven't figured out how I insert all of the extracted array values into another array with the right structure. I am hoping someone knows how to insert the values into an array so that it will be structured a la like this:

```
var newArray = [
     [foo[0], bar[0], foo2[0], bar2[0], 
     [foo[1], bar[1], foo2[1], bar2[1], 
     ...]
```

and so on until all 600 indexes are included.. I could do type all of this in by hand, but the many lines of code would make it take very long and so I am hoping one of you could tell me how to insert the extracted value in an array as shown above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Part of myArray for reference:

```
myArray = [
  {name: "name", age: age, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date", death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."},  
  {name2: "name", age2: age, job2: "occupation", works2: "published work", famous_for2: "discoveries", date_of_death2: "date", death_cause2: "cause", married2: "yes/no", spouse2: "name of spouse", country2: "country", state2: "state", economic_status2: "poor/wealthy", buried2: "graveyard", creed2: "creed", race2: "race", famous_words2: "famous words.."},
```

1 line is 1 person and there are 600 persons. I wish to only use some of the value and have extracted these values by using the

```
myArray.map(a => a.name)
myArray.map(a => a.famous_for)
myArray.map(a => a.creed)
myArray.map(a => a.race)
```

By using these values, I'm hoping the newArray would look like this:

```
var newArray = [
     [name: "name", famous_for: "discoveries", creed: "creed", race: "race", 
     [name: "name", famous_for: "discoveries", creed: "creed", race: "race", 
     ...]
```

Comment: Can you post at least part of `myArray`? so that it would be easy to identify it's structure.

Comment: It's good you add part of `myArray`, it's much clear now. If you can still add what `newArray` is actually supposed to be, just like you did for `myArray`, it would be perfect.

Comment: The other thing is that does the keys differ for all persons, like `name` for the first person and `name2` for the second person, or is it just `name`, `famous_for`, `creed`, ... for all persons?

Comment: @Addis the keys does not differ, it was just to clarify that it is different persons :) I will add the newArray in just a second! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a functional approach and use an array of keys, build functions for getting a property and map the columns.

```js
const
    data = [{name: "name", age: 99, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date", death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."}, {name: "name", age: 99, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date", death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."}],
    columns = ['name', 'famous_for', 'creed', 'race'],
    getValue = key => object => object[key],
    fns = columns.map(getValue),
    cols = o => fns.map(f => f(o)),
    table = data.map(cols);

console.log(table);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, what I would do is to add these arrays to an object with a key so it's easier to loop through.

Take a look at the example below and let me know if that is the solution you need?

```js
var myArray = [
{foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar', foo2: 'Foo2', bar2: 'Bar2' },
{foo: 'FooB', bar: 'BarB', foo2: 'FooB2', bar2: 'BarB2' },
{foo: 'FooC', bar: 'BarC', foo2: 'FooC2', bar2: 'BarC2' }
];

var foo = myArray.map(a => a.foo);
var bar = myArray.map(a => a.bar);
var foo2 = myArray.map(a => a.foo2);
var bar2 = myArray.map(a => a.bar2);

var obj = { foo, bar, foo2, bar2 };
var newArray = [];
var table = document.getElementById('table');

Object.keys(obj).forEach( (o) => newArray.push(obj[o]));



newArray.forEach(function(items) {
var row = document.createElement("tr");
    items.forEach(function(item) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.textContent = item;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<table id="table">

</table>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!! Do you happen to know how to change the position so that the output would be horizontal instead of vertical? :D

Comment: also @gugateider, could you explain to me what happens in this process: " (o) => newArray.push(obj[o]) " :)

Comment: Hi there sorry for delay, this code: `Object.keys(obj).forEach( (o) => newArray.push(obj[o]));`  what is doing is looping through all the object keys and add their value to the `newArray`

Comment: Ahh yes okay, I understand now! :) Thank you, @gugateider!

Answer (score -1):

Here's an efficient solution to your actual question:

```js
const myArray = [{name: "Sam", age: 34, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date",death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."},{name: "John", age: 25, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date",death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no",spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state:"state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy",buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."}]

// Here we iterate the input array once, rather than multiple times
const newArray = myArray.map(
  ({ name, famous_for, creed, race }) => [name, famous_for, creed, race]
)
console.log(newArray)
```

Here's a version of the above based on a couple of useful, reusable functions:

```js
const myArray = [{name: "Sam", age: 34, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date",death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."},{name: "John", age: 25, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date",death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no",spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state:"state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy",buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."}]

const getProp = key => source => source[key]
const getProps = keys => source => keys.map(key => getProp(key)(source))

const newArray = myArray.map(getProps(['name', 'famous_for', 'creed', 'race']))
console.log(newArray)
```

I'd like to point out that it isn't necessary to create an intermediate data structure, at all, given your stated final objective. This will also work (and also showcases a few best practices in manipulating DOM via JS, as a bonus):

```js
// Creating these once and cloning as needed is faster than
// creating a new one each time you need it
const tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
const tableCell = document.createElement("td");

const myArray = [{name: "Sam", age: 34, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date",death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."},{name: "John", age: 25, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date",death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no",spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state:"state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy",buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."}]

// Rather than appending one item at a time to the document,
// we build up the entire set of items and append them
// all at once, which is usually better for performance
const trs = myArray.map(({ famous_for, name, race, creed }) => {
  // Creating the array right where we need it is more efficient
  // than creating an intermediate data structure, then mapping over it
  const tds = [name, famous_for, race, creed].map(item => {
    const td = tableCell.cloneNode();
    td.textContent = item;
    return td
  });
  const tr = tableRow.cloneNode();
  tr.append(...tds)
  return tr  
});


document.getElementById('table').append(...trs)
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert the object to iterable key-value pairs, and then apply [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select the desired keys only. Finally use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to construct new object from the key-value pairs.

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    name: "Sam", age: 34, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date", 
    death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", 
    buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."
  },  
  {
    name: "John", age: 25, job: "occupation", works: "published work", famous_for: "discoveries", date_of_death: "date", 
    death_cause: "cause", married: "yes/no", spouse: "name of spouse", country: "country", state: "state", economic_status: "poor/wealthy", 
    buried: "graveyard", creed: "creed", race: "race", famous_words: "famous words.."
  }, 
]

let newArray = [];

myArray.forEach( person => {
  let obj = {};
  newArray.push( Object.entries(person).filter(entry => entry[0] === 'famous_for' || entry[0] === 'name' || entry[0] === 'creed' || entry[0] === 'race')
  .map(a => Object.assign(obj, { [a[0]] : a[1] })
  )[0] )
})

console.log(newArray)
```